# Given $b$ , $c$ and $1 = \dfrac {2a + 2ab}{c}$ solving for $a$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What rules would a person use given b and c to solve a for $1 = \dfrac {2a + 2ab}{c}$.

Specifically the established rule names for ways to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1=\dfrac {a(2+2b)}{c}$ by the distributive property, then $\dfrac {c}{2+2b}=a$ by cancelation with the multiplicative inverse of $\dfrac {2+2b}{c}$. (*Note*:$c\not=0$ and $b\not = -1$)